# An ordered set in which every closed interval is compact has LUB property.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Prove that if $X$ is an ordered set in which every closed interval is compact, then $X$ has least upper bound property.

My Solution:

Let, $A\subset X$, if $A$ contains the largest element of $X$, then we are done. Otherwise:

Suppose $U$ be the set of all upper bounds of $A$. Let, $l,l'\in U$ and $l<l'$, then the interval, $[l,l']$ is also a subset of $U$. Then $U$ contains the set of the form, $[l,\infty)$, where $l$ is an upper bound of $A$.

$a\in A$. $[a,l]$ is compact. Let $l'\in [a,l]$ is another upper bound. Let $\mathcal{A}$ is an open cover of $[a,l]$ with $A_1,\dots,A_n$ is the subcollection of $\mathcal{A}$ that also covers $[a,l]$.

1. Let, $l'\in A_i$. If there is no element of $A$ that is in $A_i$, then we choose another element from $U$(say $l''$), where $l''<l'$. If such $l''$ does not exists we immediately have $l'$ be the LUB of $A\cap [a,l]$. Suppose, there is another $l''$.
2. Let $l'\in A_i$. Suppose $a'\in A_i$ and $a'\in A$. Then again consider the interval $[a',l']$. If their is no upper bound in the interval $[a',l']$, then $l'$ is an LUB of $A\cap [a,l]$. Suppose, their is another $l''\in [a',l']$.

Now replace $l'$ by $l''$, and continue 1. and 2. we will end up to one of these: $l''$ is LUB or another upper bound $l'''<l''$

Since, $X$ has order topology, suppose $a<b$ are elements of $A$, then LUB of $A\cap [a,l]=$LUB of $A\cap [b,l]$

Hence, $X$ has LUB property.

Is this Ok. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a in A and b an upper bound of A.
Let L be the lower set of A.
$I =\ closure\ (L \cap [a,b])\ $ is a closed interval.
As I is compact, it has a max which is also supremum of A.

Comment: Does $A$ needs to have the lower set $L$, always? (I am asking since I only need to prove existence of LUB here)

Comment: Yes, to make a useful closed interval.

Comment: @William Elliot  can u elaborate... explain  what  is  L  with  example ??

Comment: L = { x : some a in A with x <= a }.   What do you mean? 'u' is not a word nor is it used in the problem.